# Liquibase tries to create DATABASECHANGELOG although it exists (Vertica)

Tags: liquibase, vertica

I have a strange problem with Liquibase (latest edition 3.2.2).

It doesn't detect that DATABASECHANGELOG already exist, so it tries to create it and fail.

How exactly does Liquibase find out if the table exist?
I went over the code from github, but couldn't figure it out (My Java skills are not strong enough and this project structure killed me...).

I'm using Vertica and I have multiple schemas in my database, and I'm trying to deploy on a specific schema called "someschema".
The executing user, someuser, has a default searchpath on someschema.

Well,
let's see some output:

1. First, I ran with updateSQL:

   ```
   $ java -jar liquibase.jar --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --classpath /opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdbc.jar --changeLogFile databaseChangeLog.json --url "jdbc:vertica://myverticahost.com:5433/insight" --username someuser --password mypwd updateSQL
   -- *********************************************************************
   -- Update Database Script
   -- *********************************************************************
   -- Change Log: databaseChangeLog.json
   -- Ran at: 9/8/14 10:19 PM
   -- Against: someuser@jdbc:vertica://myverticahost.com:5433/insight
   -- Liquibase version: 3.2.2
   -- *********************************************************************

   -- Create Database Lock Table
   CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID));

   -- Initialize Database Lock Table
   DELETE FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;

   INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE);

   -- Lock Database
   -- Create Database Change Log Table
   CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED datetime NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20));

   -- Changeset databaseChangeLog.json::1::eyaly
   create table eyal_test (id varchar(20));

   INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, LIQUIBASE) VALUES ('1', 'eyaly', 'databaseChangeLog.json', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1, '7:dc0cc25bf42c4738799e73a22426a51a', 'sql', '', 'EXECUTED', '3.2.2');
   ```
2. Then with plain update:

   ```
   $ java -jar liquibase.jar --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --classpath /opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdbc.jar --changeLogFile databaseChangeLog.json --url "jdbc:vertica://myverticahost.com:5433/insight" --username someuser --password mypwd update
   ```
3. As you can see, both table and metadata tables were created:

   ```
   dbadmin=> select * from tables where table_Schema='someschema' and (table_name ilike 'databasechange%' or table_name = 'eyal_test');
     table_schema_id  | table_schema |     table_id      |      table_name       |     owner_id      | owner_name  | is_temp_table | is_system_table | is_flextable | system_table_creator | partition_expression |          create_time          | table_definition 
   -------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+------------------
    45035996273719012 | someschema   | 63050394834440938 | DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK | 45035996273750006 | someuser    | f             | f               | f            |                      |                      | 2014-09-08 15:20:12.147975-07 | 
    45035996273719012 | someschema   | 63050394834441092 | DATABASECHANGELOG     | 45035996273750006 | someuser    | f             | f               | f            |                      |                      | 2014-09-08 15:20:13.965053-07 | 
    45035996273719012 | someschema   | 63050394834441216 | eyal_test             | 45035996273750006 | someuser    | f             | f               | f            |                          |                      | 2014-09-08 15:20:14.304429-07 | 
   (3 rows)
   dbadmin=> select * from stage.databasechangelog;
    ID | AUTHOR |        FILENAME        |        DATEEXECUTED        | ORDEREXECUTED | EXECTYPE |               MD5SUM               | DESCRIPTION | COMMENTS | TAG | LIQUIBASE 
   ----+--------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----+-----------
    1  | eyaly  | databaseChangeLog.json | 2014-09-08 15:20:14.327397 |             1 | EXECUTED | 7:dc0cc25bf42c4738799e73a22426a51a | sql         |          |     | 3.2.2
   (1 row)
   dbadmin=> select * from stage.databasechangeloglock;
    ID | LOCKED |       LOCKGRANTED       |                 LOCKEDBY                  
   ----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------
     1 | t      | 2014-09-08 22:20:12.626 | mymachine (fe80:0:0:0:2000:aff:fea4:69e%2)
   (1 row)
   ```
4. But when I run again, instead of getting no action, I get an error:

   ```
   $ java -jar liquibase.jar --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --classpath /opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdbc.jar --changeLogFile databaseChangeLog.json --url "jdbc:vertica://myverticahost.com:5433/insight" --username someuser --password mypwd update
   Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)): [Vertica][VJDBC](4213) ROLLBACK: Object "DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK" already exists
   ```

Comment: I don't believe Liquibase supports Vertica.  You can try using the `--logLevel=debug` to see what comes out.  You might be able to force it to use a Postgresql class, but looking at that code I don't think it is entirely compatible, especially around the catalog check where you are having trouble now. I can try to add support for it, I think generally it is just adding a new database class in `src / main / java / liquibase / database / core` but I probably won't have time to play with it for a couple weeks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Liquibase Vertica extension that adds support for Vertica in Liquibase. See https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Liquibase+Vertica+Extension